# Conversion from Base64 Public Key Data to SecKey and convert back from SecKey to Public Key Data are not the same. How can i resolve this?

Tags: swift, cryptography, pki, pkcs#7, pkcs#10

I am trying to convert publicKeyFromDongleData to SecKey, then perform some tasks. After that, I want to convert SecKey to b64 String. I am assuming that publicKeyFromDongleData and b64 string will be the same. But, surprisingly, they are not the same. How can i resolve the issue? Is there any way around?

My goal is to retain the public key before and after converting the same.

```
let publicKeyFromDongleData = Data.init(base64Encoded: publicKeyFromDongle)

        guard let publicKeySecKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(publicKeyFromDongleData! as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, &error) else {

                        print("Failed to create public key:", error!.takeRetainedValue())

                        return nil

                    }
        //var error:Unmanaged<CFError>?
        if let cfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKeySecKey, &error) {
           let data:Data = cfdata as Data
           let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString()
           print("after : \n")
           print(b64Key)
        }
```

the base64 string for publicKeyDongle is

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA61BjmfXGEvWmegnBGSuS
+rU9soUg2FnODva32D1AqhwdziwHINFaD1MVlcrYG6XRKfkcxnaXGfFDWHLEvNBS
EVCgJjtHAGZIm5GL/KA86KDp/CwDFMSwluowcXwDwoyinmeOY9eKyh6aY72xJh7n
oLBBq1N0bWi1e2i+83txOCg4yV2oVXhBo8pYEJ8LT3el6Smxol3C1oFMVdwPgc0v
Tl25XucMcG/ALE/KNY6pqC2AQ6R2ERlVgPiUWOPatVkt7+Bs3h5Ramxh7XjBOXeu
lmCpGSynXNcpZ/06+vofGi/2MlpQZNhHAo8eayMp6FcvNucIpUndo1X8dKMv3Y26
ZQIDAQAB
```

The bf64Key would be

```
MIIBCgKCAQEA61BjmfXGEvWmegnBGSuS
+rU9soUg2FnODva32D1AqhwdziwHINFaD1MVlcrYG6XRKfkcxnaXGfFDWHLEvNBS
EVCgJjtHAGZIm5GL/KA86KDp/CwDFMSwluowcXwDwoyinmeOY9eKyh6aY72xJh7n
oLBBq1N0bWi1e2i+83txOCg4yV2oVXhBo8pYEJ8LT3el6Smxol3C1oFMVdwPgc0v
Tl25XucMcG/ALE/KNY6pqC2AQ6R2ERlVgPiUWOPatVkt7+Bs3h5Ramxh7XjBOXeu
lmCpGSynXNcpZ/06+vofGi/2MlpQZNhHAo8eayMp6FcvNucIpUndo1X8dKMv3Y26
ZQIDAQAB
```

Later, I found out that, it's because of 2 types of header style representation for public key.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem! However, my test case can differ from yours, since I have added everything missing in your code with my data/code. So for your question to be answerable, you need to provide the missing info: 1. what key type is it: RSA, EC,...? 2. the code must be completed, currently `keyDict` is missing. 3. post a test key for `publicKeyFromDongle`.

Comment: @Topaco, i found the answer actually. If i discard first 32 bytes from publicKeyFromDongle string, it's same as b64 key. It is just for 2 different type of header for public key.

Comment: @Topaco, I added the base64 representation before and after conversion. key type is rsa.